# Node Express Middleware how to send the res, req object

Tags: node.js, express, httpresponse

I am unable to send the `res` (request object) between functions. The following code is executed by my app.js (main express middleware):

```
//app.js calls File.js

//File1.js 
var file2 = require('./File2.js);
export.modules = function (req,res,next) { 
    file2(data) {
        res.send(data); //<-- this is not working
    }
} 

//File2.js
export.modules = function(data){
    data = 'test';
}
```

Also I do not understand when to use `next()` or when to use `res.end()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its really hard to understand from you code snippets, so i will address your second question regarding next vs send

You use next inside your middlewares, which means you dont want yet to respond to your client with data, but you want to proccess the data from another middleware down the line, when you reach your final middleware you need to use res.send();

note that you cannot use res.send multiple times, so you must call it when you finished your processing and want to respond the data to the user.

you must use middleware with express as following:

```
var app = express();
app.use(function(req,res, next){
   // some proccessing
   req.proccessData = "12312312";
   next();
})

app.use(function(req,res, next){
   // here you respond the data to the client
   res.send(req.proccessData);
})
```

You can also use this with routes(get, post and etc...) Just add next as third param to the route when you want to send data to next stage

Comment: by far this is the best answer , your one statement " res.send can be used only ones" solves my understanding . Thanks a lot :) - This is solved.